# T-SQL concatenate outputs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to list dependencies for all objects in my database.
I've found this code here on stackoverflow, and it works.
But it outputs a result for each object. And I need it to be 1 table

```
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256) 
SET     @TableName = ''
WHILE   @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
SET @TableName = 
(
    SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
        AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
)

SELECT DISTINCT
    coalesce(referenced_entity_name,'') +               --very likely entity name
    coalesce('.'+col_name(referenced_ID,referenced_minor_id),'')AS [referencing],
    object_name(Referencing_ID)+                        --definite entity name
    coalesce('.'+col_name(referencing_ID,referencing_minor_id),'') AS [referenced]
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies
WHERE referenced_id =object_id(@TableName)
ORDER BY [referenced]
END
```

Current output - multiple tables.

[image]

Comment: You already have a loop. The simplest technique is to insert the rows from your SELECT query into a temp table and then select from the temp table after the end of the loop. However, the single query approach is much more efficient - a lesson to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    coalesce(referenced_entity_name,'') +               --very likely entity name
    coalesce('.'+col_name(referenced_ID,referenced_minor_id),'')AS [referencing],
    object_name(Referencing_ID)+                        --definite entity name
    coalesce('.'+col_name(referencing_ID,referencing_minor_id),'') AS [referenced]
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies
WHERE referenced_id IN (
    SELECT OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
)
ORDER BY referencing, [referenced]
```

Comment: Erm, how about `WHERE referenced_id IN (SELECT t.object_id FROM sys.tables t)`

Comment: @Charlieface: you are right, that way would be faster and more clear (I didn't think of that because I was trying to reuse the code from the question).